# Trigger on northwind

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a problem with a trigger which should do this: (On northwind)
after insert trigger that calculate the sum of prices in Order Details Table and but it in a new attribute named OrderTotal in Orders Table

I tried to do this but it's not working

```
CREATE TRIGGER TotalCalc
    ON  dbo.OrderDetails
    AFTER INSERT
AS declare @Price float , @Quan int , @Dis float , @Total float
BEGIN
    SELECT Orders.OrderId From Orders
    Select  @Price = OrderDetails.UnitPrice,
            @Quan = OrderDetails.Quantity,
            @Dis = OrderDetails.Discount,
            @Total = Orders.OrderTotal
FROM         OrderDetails INNER JOIN
                      Orders ON OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderId
    SET @Total = Sum(@Price * @Quan) - @Dis;

  Insert into Orders.OrderTotal values (@Total)

END
GO
```

Can anyone show me the way it works.

Comment: You have two `SELECT` statements, and there may be other problems.

Answer (score 0):

As you can probably guess it doesn't work. A trigger shouldn't return any `select` (your first select). And triggers suppose to use virtual tables `inserted` and `deleted`.
Finally, `Insert into Orders.OrderTotal values (@Total)` makes no sense. It creates new `orders` row which doesn't have any details like `customerid`, `employeeid`, and so on.
Try to sum linetotals from `OrderDetails` using `orderid` from `inserted` and **UPDATE** `orders.orderTotal`.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER totalsum
    ON  [dbo].[Order Details]
    AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
        DECLARE @Price float, @Quan int, @Dis float, @Total float

        SELECT
            @Price = UnitPrice,
            @Quan = Quantity,
            @Dis = Discount
        FROM
            inserted

        SET @Total= SUM(@Price * @Quan) - @Dis;

        INSERT INTO #OrdersOrderTotal VALUES (@Total)
END
```

I dear this is correct solution you just forget the inserted table and if you want check your ans is correct or not so insert the value and check your ans

```
INSERT INTO [Order Details] VALUES (11077,11,14.00,12,0)

SELECT total, SUM(total) FROM
(
    SELECT
        orderid, productid, SUM(UnitPrice * Quantity - Discount) AS total
    FROM
        [Order Details]
    GROUP BY
        OrderID, ProductID
) a
WHERE
    OrderID = 11077
    AND productiD = 11
GROUP BY
    total
```

Comment: Insert into a temp table, inside a trigger?